# Tracking user status using start date in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, vertica

I have a dataset that includes user ids, statuses corresponding to them (such as activated, expired, etc.), and the date of that status ("created").

I want to create an entry for each user daily, as long as they fall under a certain status, in order to be able to track/plot the numbers of users per month for their statuses.

E.g. A user on 2019-01-01 18:30:00 has status 'ACTIVATED', then on 2020-01-01 19:53:01 has status 'EXPIRED', then on 2020-02-01 has status 'ACTIVATED' again until the current date.

I would thus want that user ID and status to appear between the first and second date as 'ACTIVATED', between the second and third date as 'EXPIRED', and from the third date until the current date as 'ACTIVATED'.

I am pretty lost on how to do this, but from some research online I got/modified this piece of code, which is written in Vertica. However, it is not written in the correct dialect, and does not incorporate status in the way I would like.

```
SELECT id,
       status_dt,
       last_order_dt,
       CASE
           WHEN status_dt::date - last_order_dt::date < 30 then CASE
           WHEN nord = 1 then 'New'
           ELSE 'Active'
           END
           WHEN status_dt::date - last_order_dt::date < 90 then 'Active'
           WHEN status_dt::date - last_order_dt::date < 180 then 'Passive'
           ELSE 'Inactive'
       END AS status
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          last_order_dt,
          status_dt,
          conditional_true_event (first_order_dt is null
          OR last_order_dt > lag(last_order_dt)) OVER(partition BY id
          ORDER BY status_dt) AS nord
   FROM
     ( SELECT id,
              ts_first_value(created) AS first_order_dt,
              ts_last_value(created) AS last_order_dt,
              dt::date AS status_dt
      FROM
        (SELECT id,
                created
         FROM enabled
         UNION all SELECT distinct(id) AS id,
                          current_date + 1 AS created
         FROM enabled ) z timeseries dt AS '1 day' OVER(partition BY id
         ORDER BY created) ) x ) y
WHERE status_dt <= current_date
ORDER BY 1,
         2 ;

with t AS
  ( SELECT id,
           [created],
           current_date,
           status
   FROM postgres_public.loc_application_status
   UNION all SELECT id,
                    dateadd(mm, 1, [created]),
                    current_date,
                    status
   FROM t
   WHERE dateadd(mm, 1, [created]) < coalesce(current_date, getdate()) )
SELECT id,
       [created],
       (CASE
            WHEN eomonth([created]) <= coalesce(current_date, cast(getdate() AS date)) then eomonth([created])
            ELSE coalesce(current_date, eomonth([created]))
        END) AS current_date,
       status
FROM t
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: For starters, `[created]` should be `created` - the square brackets are invalid in standard SQL. And `dateadd(mm, 1, [created]),` should probably be `crated + interval '1 month'`. Not sure what `getdate()` is doing, but `coalesce(current_date, getdate())` looks quite strange as `current_date` never returns `null`. I don't know what `eomonth` does

Comment: Yeah, it was just the only somewhat similar I could find online. I'm not sure if it's even really useful in writing the code that achieves the function I described

Comment: Please include an example of the expected output given your scenario. You say there should be daily values per person. What happens on the day that the status changes? On 2020-01-01, should user A have a row for ACTIVATED, EXPIRED, or both?

Comment: Because there is a timestamp, there could be a row with the time at the last moment a user had the status 'ACTIVATED', and the following row 'EXPIRED', but it is not necessary, depending on how much it makes the problem more complex. The main thing I want to achieve is just being able to track users' statuses every day in order to also be able to know, for example, how many active users I have per month.

Comment: Already the Vertica dialect of the query looks a bit over-complicated to me. Using a `TIMESERIES` to track changes in status, rather than from-to date ranges is a dangerous activity, and needs to be done only when unavoidable - as much as I love the `TIMESERIES` clause ... Can you not  add a small sample of your `enabled` table, so we can play with it?